# How to get list of dict instead of using collection.defaultdict in python

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary, yaml

I am trying to convert a list into nested dictionaries recursively as following :-

Given Input :-

```
parse_list = ['A','B','C','D']
```

Required Output :-

```
data = [
    {'name': 'A',
     'childs': [
         {'name': 'B',
          'childs': [
              {'name': 'C',
               'childs': [
                   {'name': 'D',
                    'childs': none }]}]}]}]
```

My code:-

```
from collections import defaultdict
class_dict =defaultdict(list)
data =defaultdict(list)
parse_list.reverse()

def create_dict(parse_list,class_dict):
    for index ,listitem in enumerate(parse_list):
        new_class_dict = defaultdict(list)
        new_class_dict.__setitem__('name', listitem)
        new_class_dict['childs'].append(class_dict)
        class_dict = new_class_dict
    return class_dict

data = create_dict(parse_list,class_dict) 
import yaml
with open('data.yml', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write( yaml.dump(data, default_flow_style=False))
```

However because of defaultdict(list), I always get many extra indent in yaml, which are not expected. Is there any other way to get the [{....}] instead of using collection.defaultdict.

Comment: **ARGH!!!** Why are you calling `__setitem__` directly?!? Also, your code doesn't really need `defaultdict` since you only and always create one key.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply @Bakuriu. Here I am using __setitem__ because the next entry ['childs'] is also a list of dictionary. And its the simplest model as I need to expend the childs for multiple entries at different levels in further development. Is there any other way then please suggest.

Comment: What I mean is that `new_class_dict.__setitem__('name', listitem)` is *exactly* equivalent to `new_class_dict['name'] = listitem`. Actualy *it's slower* because it requires an extra method lookup. If you ever call directly a method with double underscores in its name *you are doing something wrong* (there are a few exceptions, but not for beginners).

Comment: Thanks @Bakuriu , I learned this style from some other post on stack overflow. But thanks a lot for this explanation. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a recursive way

```
parse_list = ['A','B','C','D']



def createdict(l, d):
    if len(l) == 0:
        return None
    d = dict()
    d['name'] = l[0]
    d['childs'] = [createdict(l[1:], d)]
    return d

resultDict = createdict(parse_list, dict())
```

Comment: oh have not seen the other answer... so might be an alternative solution

Comment: thanks but when I tried this code, I got the following output :- {'childs': {'childs': [{...}], 'name': 'B'}, 'name': 'A'} . And inside [{...}], it contains repetitively the next dict for B only.

Comment: oh there was a tiny mistake :) sorry

Comment: and one more tiny error now                       resultDict = createdict(parse_list) instead of resultDict = createdict(parse_list, dict()) .But this is what I was looking for using recursively. Thanks a lot ...

Answer (score 2):

You can acheive it simply like this

```
parse_list = ['A','B','C','D']

dicton={}

for i in reversed(parse_list):
    dicton['child']=[dicton]
    dicton['name']=i


print dicton
#output {'name': 'A', 
         'child': [{'name': 'B', 
                     'child': [{'name': 'C', 
                                'child': [{'name': 'D', 
                                            'child': [{}]
                                                         }]}]}]}
```

Comment: Note that, if performance matters, the recursive answers should be preferred, because here you're recreating the dict at each step. Otherwise, nice solution!

Comment: @SébastienDeprez i dint get you can you explain correctly.so that i will learn

Comment: With `dict(dicton)` you re copying all the contents of `dicton` in a new dict.

Comment: @SébastienDeprez does that cause any side effects ?

Comment: No all, it's perfectly working! I was just noticing the point for performance issues.

Comment: You can avoid the copy: `dicton = {}; for name in reversed(parse_list): dicton = {'name': name, 'child': dicton}`.

Comment: @Bakuriu i gave like that but it gives me out put {'name':a ,'child':{...}} like this

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар I just tried that exact code on my machine and it works perfectly. I believe you mistyped something. See: `>>> s = 'ABCD';d={}
>>> for x in s[::-1]:d={'name':x, 'child':d}
... 
>>> print(d)
{'name': 'A', 'child': {'name': 'B', 'child': {'name': 'C', 'child': {'name': 'D', 'child': {}}}}}
`   If you `child` should be a list of dicts you can simply change `'child': d` to `'child': [d]`.

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар No, but that code is perfectly python2.7 compatible (also I just tested it under python2.7 and works fine).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive solution

```
parse_list = ['A','B','C','D']

def descend(l):
    if l:
        return [{'name': l[0],
                'childs': descend(l[1:])}]
    else:
        return None

data = descend(parse_list)
```