# Python list to nested keys

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im trying to create/populate a nested dictionary from a list.

For example, a list `[['a','b','c'],value]`  could create:

```
data['a']['b']['c'] = value
```

Giving me a dictionary:

```
{ 'a': { 'b': { 'c' : value } } }
```

All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be similar:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934964/how-to-get-list-of-dict-instead-of-using-collection-defaultdict-in-python

Comment: This is also close, though a slightly different problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692690/access-python-nested-dictionary-items-via-a-list-of-keys

Comment: Consider using a non-nested dictionary, keyed by tuples. Then you can just do `d = {}; d['a', 'b', 'c'] = value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Assuming that you have more than one of those multi-key/value pairs.)

You can use `setdefault` to add nested dictionaries for all the sub-key, unless they already exist, each time continuing with that new one for all but the last sub-key. Then put the value into the innermost dict.

```
def add_nested(d, keys, value):
    for k in keys[:-1]:
        d = d.setdefault(k, {})
    d[keys[-1]] = value
```

Example:

```
values = [
    [['a','b','c'], 1],
    [['a','b','d'], 2],
    [['a','e','f'], 3]]

result = {}
for keys, value in values:
    add_nested(result, keys, value)
print(result)
```

Result:

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': 1, 'd': 2}, 'e': {'f': 3}}}
```

---

Alternatively, you could also use the good old [infinite dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12414913/1639625):

```
infinidict = lambda: collections.defaultdict(infinidict)
result = infinidict()
for keys, value in values:
    last = reduce(operator.getitem, keys[:-1], result)
    last[keys[-1]] = value
```

Comment: This is a good answer. I don't think the question should be ticked as "too broad".

Answer (score 3):

Python:

```
l = [['a', 'b', 'c'], 'foo']
d = l[1]
for k in l[0][::-1]:
    d = {k : d}
print d
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': 'foo'}}}
```

Comment: Why not just `d = l[1]` then in the loop `d = {k : d}`?

Comment: @jojo Yes, thanks for the simplification.

Answer (score 0):

Use generator and recursive style:

```
a = [
     [['a','b','c'],1],
     [['c','d'],1],
    ]

def l2d(a):
    def mkd(k,v):
        if not k:
            return v
        return {k[0]:mkd(k[1:],v)}
    for k, v in a:
        yield mkd(k,v)

for d in l2d(a):
    print d
```

Result:

```
>>> 
{'a': {'b': {'c': 1}}}
{'c': {'d': 1}}
```