# Converting a list to a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

What is the most pythonic way to convert:

```
A = [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]
```

where "A" can be a list with any number of elements to

```
B = {a1: {a2: {a3: {a4: {a5: y}}}}}
```

where y is some variable.

Comment: *Creating* the nested dictionaries or simply *traversing* the existing indexable object graph?

Comment: creating a nested dictionary

Comment: but what do you mean by 'simply traversing the existing indexable object graph'

Comment: Eg. reading or setting the value in an already existing nested-array/dictionary structure (such as from some deserialized JSON).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python list to nested keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326180/python-list-to-nested-keys)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def build_dict(A, y):
    for s in reversed(A):
        y = {s: y}
    return y

A = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5']
y = 'some value'
print(build_dict(A, y))
```

output:

```
{'a1': {'a2': {'a3': {'a4': {'a5': 'some value'}}}}}
```

---

Alternative using [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) ([`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) in Python 3.x):

```
>>> A = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5']
>>> y = 'some value'
>>> reduce(lambda x, s: {s: x}, reversed(A), y)
{'a1': {'a2': {'a3': {'a4': {'a5': 'some value'}}}}}
```

Comment: nice ,i was using recursion,this looks much better

Comment: @abstract, I added an alternative that use `reduce`.